# Return variable from DB2 into resultset

Tags: c#, sql, db2

From my C# application I want to get a shipmentnumber from the database, if the record does not exist then I will create it and return the new shipmentnumber. Now I have created a stored procedure in DB2, in this I declared a variable called SHIPNR as a decimal.
Now I want this variable returned as a resultset. I have this part of a code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE SHIPMENTNR DECIMAL ( 6 , 0 ) ;

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT PHSHIP
        FROM THEPRDDTA . WSHP010
        WHERE PHORD = ORDNR AND
            PHID = 'PH' ;

    OPEN C1 ;
    FETCH FROM C1 INTO SHIPMENTNR ;
    CLOSE C1 ;

    IF ( SHIPMENTNR IS NULL ) THEN
    //do something
    END IF ;

    BEGIN
    DECLARE C_OUT CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DATA
        FROM BPCSF . ZPAL01
        WHERE PKEY = 'THETSHIP' ;

    OPEN C_OUT ;

    END ;

END
```

This works perfect and returns the 'DATA' I selected. So the code is working (well the if statement is not yet tested, but thats up to me :) so I didn't enclosed it) I don't want to get it as a parameter.

So the question: How do I return the decimal 'SHIPMENTNR' as a resultset to my application?

Comment: If you're just getting a single value why are you trying to return a cursor?  Just use an OUT parameter in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, instead of using a a stored procedure that will return a result set of one row with just one column, I will use a function (UDF)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE GET_SHIPMENT_NUMBER(
  ORDNR INTEGER
  ) RETURNS DECIMAL(6, 0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE SHIPMENTNR DECIMAL(6, 0) ;

  SET SHIPMENTNR = (
    SELECT PHSHIP
    FROM THEPRDDTA.WSHP010
    WHERE PHORD = ORDNR AND
        PHID = 'PH');

  IF (SHIPMENTNR IS NULL) THEN
  //do something
  END IF ;

  RETURN SHIPMENTNR;
END
```

Comment: Well, didn't used a function before, let's give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to return an opened cursor, you need to define the cursor with the option 'with return' and to caller or to client.

You can also limit the returned results sets with "dynamic result sets X"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_SHIPMENT_NUMBER(
  ORDNR INTEGER
  )
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
  DECLARE SHIPMENTNR DECIMAL(6, 0) ;

  DECLARE C_OUT CURSOR
    WITH RETURN TO CALLER
    FOR
    SELECT DATA
    FROM BPCSF.ZPAL01
    WHERE PKEY = 'THETSHIP' ;

  SET SHIPMENTNR = (
    SELECT PHSHIP
    FROM THEPRDDTA.WSHP010
    WHERE PHORD = ORDNR AND
        PHID = 'PH');

  IF (SHIPMENTNR IS NULL) THEN
  //do something
  END IF ;

  OPEN C_OUT ;
END
```

References:

- Declare cursor: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html
- Create procedure: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html

Comment: Well in my code I got already an result in my program. I want to have the variable SHIPMENTNR, the SHIPMENTNR in the ZPAL01 table is always the beggiest SHIPMENTNR, so the program can return the newest SHIPMENTNR what it got from ZPAL01 or the SHIPMENTNR in WSHP010